# View old/past snoozed emails in Outlook

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

In [Outlook](https://outlook.office.com/mail/), I sometimes snooze emails because I am on the go or busy and want to look at them later and they are probably important.

However, when the day or time that I was supposed to take a look at the email comes, it gets buried, I forget, etc.

How can I find all those snoozed emails I intended to see "later" but that "later" is now in the past?

If I go to the "Snoozed" folder, it only shows me emails that I snoozed to a time in the future, but not the emails that I snoozed to a time now in the past.

[image: snoozed folder]